# Django loads parent object when it's not required

Tags: django, django-orm

Here is my simplified models configuration:

```
class Topic(Sortable):
    course = SortableForeignKey(Course)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    estimated_time = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True))

class Task(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)

class Quiz(Task):
    questions = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'[#%s] %s: %s' % (self.id, self.topic.title, capitalize(_("quiz")))
```

As you can see, there is a Topic related as one-to-many with Task (non-abstract model). Quiz is one of the Task inheritors. I want to select all quizzes related with a particular topic. I need only quiz's own field `questions` and its `task_ptr_id` - no topic data needed. Here is my statement:

```
Quiz.objects.only('task_ptr_id', 'task_ptr__topic_id', 'questions').filter(topic_id=topic_id)
```

When I execute it, two database queries are executed:

```
(0.001) SELECT "website_task"."id", "website_task"."topic_id", "website_quiz"."task_ptr_id", "website_quiz"."questions" FROM "website_quiz" INNER JOIN "website_task" ON ( "website_quiz"."task_ptr_id" = "website_task"."id" ) WHERE "website_task"."topic_id" = 1 LIMIT 21; args=(1,)
(0.000) SELECT "website_topic"."id", "website_topic"."order", "website_topic"."course_id", "website_topic"."publish", "website_topic"."title", "website_topic"."text", "website_topic"."estimated_time" FROM "website_topic" WHERE "website_topic"."id" = 1 LIMIT 21; args=(1,)
```

Why it executes second one if all required data are returned by the first one?

Comment: Which Django version are you running?

Comment: Which DB engine? With SQLite3 and 1.7.2 (and 1.7.4), I get a single query (albeit with a JOIN):
(0.000) QUERY = u'SELECT "quiz_task"."id", "quiz_task"."topic_id", "quiz_quiz"."task_ptr_id", "quiz_quiz"."questions" FROM "quiz_quiz" INNER JOIN "quiz_task" ON ( "quiz_quiz"."task_ptr_id" = "quiz_task"."id" ) WHERE "quiz_task"."topic_id" = %s LIMIT 21' - PARAMS = (1,); args=(1,)`

Comment: In what context are you executing the query?

Comment: @MarkR., I use PostgreSQL 9.4. Interesting that you see only one query...

Comment: @BernhardVallant, what do you mean by context here?

Comment: @MarkR., thank you a lot for trying it. You didn't see second query because I posted simplified Quiz model without `__unicode__` method that contained `return u'[#%s] %s: %s' % (self.id, self.topic.title, capitalize(_("quiz")))`. My fail... thank you for your help in finding this. Please write the answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, posting as an answer: always check that you're not referencing other models.